# How many unused inputs are there in a BCD adder?

Tags: circuit-design, adder

My book provides this BCD adder with the truth table:
[image]
[image]

Since this is meant to add number in BCD there are combinations that aren't going to be used. My book asks to calculate how many of such combinations are there. I did:

$$[(6*9)*2+(6*6)*2]*2 = 360$$

6*9 is the valid ones times the invalid ones. 6*6 is the invalid ones. I multiply each of these by two because you can have them one way around or the other. Lastly I multiplied by 2 because the input carry can be either 1 or 0.  But my book says the solution is 312. What went wrong?

Comment: There are \$16\times 16\$ possibilities without the carry. This is doubled when you add in the carry, so there are a total of \$2\times 16\times 16=512\$ possible input permutations. Out of this, only  \$2\times 10\times 10=200\$ are valid inputs -- obviously. Therefore, the answer is \$512-200=312\$. I honestly don't want to understand your own confusion here, so I didn't try to dig in enough to follow where you went wrong in your head. But it's wrong.

Comment: @jonk Looking at your answer I think I know what went wrong. I multiplied by 9 instead of 10. Thanks

Comment: Okay. If that gets it, great! It's certainly the case that there is 0-9, or 10 valid permutations for each input. Glad it helped. Best wishes!

Answer (score 1):

Like you commented, you have to multiply with 10 instead of 9.
There is however another point incorrect.

You need to add the invalid ones times the invalid ones **once**, so

$$[(6*\color{red}{10})*2+(6*6)*\color{red}{1}]*2 = 312$$

To link your approach with Jonk's approach:
Defining variable a the number of valid BCD codes (a=10), b the number of invalid BCD codes (b=6) and a+b (therefore) the total number of codes,

Jonk's approach is
$$ 2*((a+b)^2-a^2) $$
Rewriting 
$$ 2*((a+b)^2-a^2) = $$
$$ 2*(a^2+2ab+b^2-a^2) = $$
$$2*( 2ab + b^2 ) $$ 
which is your approach.

Comment: I think my approach is ***way*** easier to understand and lots less likely to go wrong, because it avoids getting mired in unnecessary detail that makes it more likely to make a mistake in the process. But what do I know?

Comment: @jonk I also think you're way is absolute easier. But OP's approach is valid too. It was by writing out your approach I found another error in OP's elaboration. Regarding your last question: from what I've seen a lot!